# Programming issue in Stata

Tags: stata

Consider the folowing problem: we have the already defined variables logA, logT, logtK and logtY with values for firms along different countries (variable country).
We aim at providing tables with three key columns:
the difference between 90th and 10th percentile, the inter-quartile range and the standard deviation.

I am not a Stata expert, but the code seem too convoluted for obtaining these simple statistics. I am looking for a much simpler solution.

The following lines lead to an error:

```
foreach var in logA logT logtK logtY{
 forvalues z= 1(1)2{
     preserve
     if `z'==1 table country , c(p50 `var') replace
     if `z'==2 table country , c(sd  `var' p25 `var' p75 `var' p10 `var' p90 `var') replace
     gen variable = "`var'"
     tempfile file`z'_`var'
     sort country
     save `file`z'_`var'', replace
     restore
 }    
}
```

This works fine...

```
preserve
foreach var in logA logT logtK logtY{
      use `file1_`var'', clear
      ren table1 table6
      merge country using `file2_`var''
      tempfile file_`var'
      save `file_`var'', replace
}
```

But this block leads to the following error:

```
invalid file specification
r(198);
```

Finally, the code for this/these table(s) ends with:

```
foreach file in logTFPRsi logtau_Ksi logtau_Ysi{
 append using `file_`file''
}

ren table1 sd
gen p75_p25 = table3-table2
gen p90_p10 = table5-table4
gen p50_p10 = table6-table4
gen p50 = table6
drop table* _merge
order variable country 
sort  variable country
outsheet using "Table1.csv", comma names replace
restore
```

Comment: You may well need `" "` around your filename in the `save` command if the directory or folder in which you create `tempfile`s has a name containing a space. A different issue is that there is no point in saving temporary files if you do nothing with them. Perhaps that is to be worked out in later code.

Comment: Note that using `collapse` is here a better strategy for saving summary statistics. It would avoid your work-around of an inner loop in which you repeat stuff.

Comment: Also, it is not clear whether you have defined all the local macros and/or tempnames you have used in the second segment. In fact, too much in total of your code is unexplained for this to be a clear question.

Comment: The edit doesn't address any of the previous 3 comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of messing around with files here that seems quite unnecessary. In this code, the only looping is just to build up the syntax for a single call to `collapse`:

```
* invented dataset with same structure 
clear 
set obs 20 
gen country = cond(_n <= 10, "A", "B") 
set seed 2803
foreach v in logA logT logtK logtY { 
    gen `v' = runiform()
}

* blank out local macro, just in case 
local call 

* the heart of the matter is: just use collapse! 
foreach v in logA logT logtK logtY { 
    local call `call' (p10) p10`v' = `v' 
    local call `call' (p25) p25`v' = `v' 
    local call `call' (p75) p75`v' = `v' 
    local call `call' (p90) p90`v' = `v' 
    local call `call' (sd)  sd`v' = `v' 
}

collapse `call', by(country)
```

Now the interquantile ranges, p90 - p10 and p75 - p25, are just to be obtained by subtraction.